# How to merge cells in python3

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x

I am trying to merge two cells together in python3. I would appreciate for any input.

Here is a part of my script:

```
with open(input) as infile, open (output, 'w') as outfile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter='\t')
    writer = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter='\t')
    for gg, poss, codee, ref, alt, *rest in reader:
        gg = int(gg)
        poss = int(poss)
        writer.writerow([gg, poss, codee, d[group][poss-1], "ref+alt"] + rest)
```

I am trying to have column "ref" to merge with "alt" ("ref+alt" in the last line) , so my column will consist of column "gg", "poss", "codee", "d[group][poss-3]", and "ref"+"alt".

The "ref" column looks like:

```
A
B
C
```

while "alt" column has multiple letters separated by comma:

```
A,B
C,D,H
B,F,S
```

What would be the correct way to write the last line so that "ref" and "alt" get merged like this?

```
A,A,B
B,C,D,H
C,B,F,S
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"ref+alt"` is just the string `ref+alt` but it doesn’t actually evaluate those variables (it really shouldn’t). If you want to concatenate two strings, you can use the `+` operator on those variables:

```
ref + alt
```

And if you want to insert a comma in between, you can also add that:

```
ref + ',' + alt
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the expression: `','.join((v for v in (ref, alt) if v))` which will leave out the command if either`ref`or`alt`is`None`or the empty string`''`.